# How to change the fill of aggregation association to "no fill"

Tags: enterprise-architect

Is it possible to change the fill colour of the diamonds in connectors? Specifically, I want to change the aggregation association diamond from its current fill (a pinkish-yellow colour) to "no fill" or, if that isn't possible, to white.

Edit: Here's a screenshot of what I'm talking about. I would have expected there to be no fill (transparent or maybe just white).

[image: Example of aggregation association connector fill]

Comment: There are only shared (hollow) and composite (filled black) aggregations. So, what is that pinkish thingy you're talking about? Picture?

Comment: @ThomasKilian I've edited my post to show what I see. That association is aggregation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. At least not without other side effects. The color you see is what EA uses to fill elements which otherwise are not filled. But since connectors are 2nd class citizens in EA you can not change the fill color like you can do it for elements (probably because most connectors are just 2D renderings). You can see that also with generalizations:

[image]

So what can you do? There are 2 ways.

1. Go to the diagram properties and check whiteboard mode:

   [image]

   This will remove all colors and you end up with this:

   [image]
2. Open Tools/Options and alter the Default Fill Color to white:

   [image]

   This will yield this appearance:

   [image]

Although it's possible to use a shape script to create a really hollow (or white filled) diamond, this is not recommended. In this case you'd need to apply a stereotype and that's likely not what you intend.

Comment: You might send a feature request to Sparx. But don't hold your breath. Those times are over since more than 12 years.

Comment: I'll try whiteboard mode. Or maybe I can change the default colour in EA to just be white?